# how to disable a control in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("ctrl").disabled = true;
```

this works in IE but does not works in mozila. What shoul I do?

Comment: What type of DOM element is `ctrl`? Can you post some HTML to go with your JavaScript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you try:

```
document.getElementById("ctrl").setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Why does this work better than using `.disabled = true`?

Comment: This question is from 2010. Mozilla have implemented the direct `.disabled` since then.

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="disabled(this);"/>
    <script>
        function disabled(ctrl) {
            ctrl.disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what the issue is that you are having.  Does [mozilla](/questions/tagged/mozilla) do anything when the code is executed? does it display an error?  What version of [ie](/questions/tagged/ie) did you test it with?  And can you also provide the [html](/questions/tagged/html) for the `ctrl` element?

One of the issue with IE and the `getElementById` method is that in some versions of the browser it will match on the `id` attribute of a tag as well as the `name` attribute (which does not follow the [JavaScript spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId)).  In Mozilla it is only matching using the `id` attribute.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437(VS.85).aspx